# Slicing sublists with different lengths

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

I have a list of lists. Each sublist has a length that varies between 1 and 100. Each sublist contains a particle ID at different times in a set of data. I would like to form lists of all particle IDs at a given time. To do this I could use something like:

```
    list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,6,7,8],[1,3,6,7,8]]
    list2 = [item[0] for item in list]
```

list2 would contain the first elements of each sublist in list. I would like to do this operation not just for the first element, but for every element between 1 and 100. My problem is that element number 100 (or 66 or 77 or whatever) does not exists for every sublist.

Is there some way of creating a lists of lists, where each sublist is the list of all particle IDs at a given time.

I have thought about trying to use numpy arrays to solve this problem, as if the lists were all the same length this would be trivial. I have tried adding -1's to the end of each list to make them all the same length, and then masking the negative numbers, but this hasn't worked for me so far. I will use the list of IDs at a given time to slice another separate array:

```
    pos = pos[satIDs]
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with one line for loop? or any for loop would do?

Comment: Any loop will do, however the dataset is quite large so speed could be an issue.

Comment: "masking the negative numbers, but this hasn't worked for me so far" - How didn't that work out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,6,7,8],[1,3,6,7,8]]
func =  lambda x: [line[x] for line in lst if len(line) > x]

func(3)
[4, 8, 7]
func(4)
[5, 8]
```

--update--

```
func =  lambda x: [ (line[x],i) for i,line in enumerate(lst) if len(line) > x]
func(4)
[(5, 0), (8, 2)]
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, is there also a way to track which element in func(x) came from which list e.g. an addtional list which says that (for func(4)), 5 came from sublist 0 and 8 came from sublist 2?

Comment: ... what's the point of using a `lambda` and then assigning it to a name? Just use `def func(x): return [line [x] ...]`.

Comment: @Jack updated. the first element in tuple is value and second is number of sublist

Comment: @Bakuriu agree with you

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest). This will `zip` the lists together and insert `None` when one of the lists is exhausted.

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3,4,5],['A','B','C'],['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']]    
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(*lst))
[(1, 'A', 'a'),
 (2, 'B', 'b'),
 (3, 'C', 'c'),
 (4, None, 'd'),
 (5, None, 'e'),
 (None, None, 'f'),
 (None, None, 'g')]
```

If you don't want the `None` elements, you can filter them out:

```
>>> [[x for x in sublist if x is not None] for sublist in itertools.zip_longest(*lst)]
[[1, 'A', 'a'], [2, 'B', 'b'], [3, 'C', 'c'], [4, 'd'], [5, 'e'], ['f'], ['g']]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

One almost* vectorized approach could be suggested that goes along creating ID based on the new order and splitting, like so -

```
def position_based_slice(L):

    # Get lengths of each element in input list
    lens = np.array([len(item) for item in L])

    # Form ID array that has *ramping* IDs within an element starting from 0
    # and restarts with a new element at 0
    id_arr = np.ones(lens.sum(),int)
    id_arr[lens[:-1].cumsum()] = -lens[:-1]+1

    # Get order maintained sorted indices for sorting flattened version of list
    ids = np.argsort(id_arr.cumsum(),kind='mergesort')

    # Get sorted version and split at boundaries decided by lengths of ids
    vals = np.take(np.concatenate(L),ids)
    cut_idx = np.where(np.diff(ids)<0)[0]+1
    return np.split(vals,cut_idx)
```

*There is a loop comprehension involved at the start, but being meant to collect just the lengths of the input elements of the list, its effect on the total runtime should be minimal.

Sample run -

```
In [76]: input_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,6,7,8],[1,3,6,7,8],[3,2]]

In [77]: position_based_slice(input_list)
Out[77]: 
[array([1, 2, 1, 3]), # input_list[ID=0]
 array([2, 6, 3, 2]), # input_list[ID=1]
 array([3, 7, 6]),    # input_list[ID=2]
 array([4, 8, 7]),    # input_list[ID=3]
 array([5, 8])]       # input_list[ID=4]
```

**Approach #2**

Here's another approach that creates a `2D` array, which is easier to index and trace back to original input elements. This uses NumPy broadcasting alongwith boolean indexing. The implementation would look something like this -

```
def position_based_slice_2Dgrid(L):

    # Get lengths of each element in input list
    lens = np.array([len(item) for item in L])

    # Create a mask of valid places in a 2D grid mapped version of list
    mask = lens[:,None] > np.arange(lens.max())
    out = np.full(mask.shape,-1,dtype=int)
    out[mask] = np.concatenate(L)
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [126]: input_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,6,7,8],[1,3,6,7,8],[3,2]]

In [127]: position_based_slice_2Dgrid(input_list)
Out[127]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  6,  7,  8, -1],
       [ 1,  3,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  2, -1, -1, -1]])
```

So, now each column of the output would correspond to your ID based outputting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it with a `one-line forloop` and in an `array` you can do this:

```
list2 = [[item[i] for item in list if len(item) > i] for i in range(0, 100)]
```

And if you want to know which id is from which list you can do this:

```
list2 = [{list.index(item): item[i] for item in list if len(item) > i} for i in range(0, 100)]
```

list2 would be like this:

```
[{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1}, {0: 2, 1: 6, 2: 3}, {0: 3, 1: 7, 2: 6}, {0: 4, 1: 8, 2: 7},
 {0: 5, 2: 8}, {}, {}, ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append `numpy.nan` to your short lists and afterwards create a numpy array

```
import numpy
import itertools

lst = [[1,2,3,4,5],[2,6,7,8],[1,3,6,7,8,9]]
arr = numpy.array(list(itertools.izip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=numpy.nan)))
```

Afterwards you can use numpy slicing as usual.

```
print arr
print arr[1, :]   # [2, 6, 3]
print arr[4, :]   # [5, nan, 8]
print arr[5, :]   # [nan, nan, 9]
```

Comment: If I did a slice in this way, would I be able to tell which row each element in my sliced array had come from? I.e. would it keep the nans?

Comment: Yes of course. whenever you run past the end of any of the lists that entry becomes a `nan`.

Comment: But would I then be able to use the slice array, eg x = [nan,nan,9] to perform a slice of another array, data[x] - would this not give me an error? IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: You are trying to use the resulting list as indices? Sorry I didn't read that in your post.