# Python: how to splice a list into sublists of given lengths?

Tags: python, list

```
x = [2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2]
```

I want to splice the above list into sublists of `length = [1, 2, 3, 1]`. In other words, I want my output to look something like this:

```
[[2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [2]]
```

where my first sublist is of length 1, the second sublist is of length 2, and so forth.

Comment: Is `sum(length) == len(x)` ?

Comment: @JonClements, that is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224821/slicing-sublists-with-different-lengths this here, but it didn't do what I was looking for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` here to consume N many elements of the source list each iteration, eg:

```
from itertools import islice

x = [2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2]
length = [1, 2, 3, 1]
# get an iterable to consume x
it = iter(x)
new_list = [list(islice(it, n)) for n in length]
```

Gives you:

```
[[2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [2]]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if `x = [2, '', '', 2, '', '', '']`? I think using `islice` did not give the desired result of `[[2], ['', ''], [2, '', ''], ['']]`

Answer (score 0):

Basically we want to extract certain lengths of substrings. 
For that we need a start_index and an end_index. The end_index is your start_index + the current length which we want to extract:

```
x = [2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2]    
lengths = [1,2,3,1]

res = []
start_index = 0
for length in lengths:
    res.append(x[start_index:start_index+length])
    start_index += length

print(res)  # [[2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [2]]
```

Added this solution to the other answer as it does not need any imported modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following listcomp:

```
from itertools import accumulate

x = [2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2]
length = [1, 2, 3, 1]

[x[i - j: i] for i, j in zip(accumulate(length), length)]
# [[2], [1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [2]]
```